# Как предотвратить неявное преобразование строки в bool

Tags: c++

Функция, принимающая булево значение:

```
void foo(bool b) {
    if (b)
        std::cout << "true\n";
    else
        std::cout << "false\n";
}
```

вызывается (по ошибке) как:

```
foo("false");
```

и выводит "true", т.к. при вызове строка "false" неявно преобразовывается в bool со значением true. Можно ли как-то ограничить возможность вызова функции `foo(bool)` с отличным от bool параметром.

В действии: https://wandbox.org/permlink/25Zv09CM9jyAZcjG

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12877563/9210255

Comment: @TigerTV.ru тоже здорово, но опасно - надо будет для остальных типов тоже прописывать (для int, указателей и прочих), и не забыть ничего

Comment: да, все верно, опасно.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно сделать эту функцию шаблоном или добавить запрещенные перегрузки для типов, которые могут быть неявно преобразованы в bool:

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename x_MustBeBool >
void foo(x_MustBeBool) = delete;

template<>
void foo< bool >(bool b) {
    if (b)
        std::cout << "true\n";
    else
        std::cout << "false\n";
}

int main()
{
    foo(true); // OK
    foo("false"); // Error
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3678j5

Comment: Coool! А для функций-членов можно такой фокус проделать?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Можно.